# How to return a class with a generic type by passing in the type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class which uses a generic type,

```
public class BaseClass<T> {
  public T Data { get; set; }
  public BaseClass(T data) {
    this.Data = data;
  }
  public BaseClass() { }
}
```

I want to create a method that returns a `BaseClass<T>` object, so I'm trying this:

```
public BaseClass<T> NoData() {
  return new BaseClass<T>(null);
}
```

and call it with something like `return NoData<MyTClass>();`

I'm getting an error tho with the `<T>`, `The type or namespace 'T' cannot be found`

Is this possible to do in c#? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a generic parameter to the method name:

```
public BaseClass<T> NoData<T>() {
  return new BaseClass<T>(null);
}
```

But since you don't specify that `T` is a class, you need to use the more general `default(T)`:

```
public BaseClass<T> NoData<T>() {
  return new BaseClass<T>(default(T));
}
```

And since you have a default constructor that essentially does the same thing you could also do:

```
public BaseClass<T> NoData<T>() {
  return new BaseClass<T>();
}
```

Comment: but since T can be any type: return new BaseClass<T>(default(T));